# How to use transform tool in meshmixer

Tags: meshmixer

I have tried to add a base to teeth model. I am not fan of using extrude tool because it is slow acc. to my experience.

After selecting border, I did smooth operation on the border. After that, I have tried to use transform tool but it did not transform the border in any direction.

I have video tutorial to follow in youtube -->

What I did is that [image]

Is it related with meshmixer version? Is it a bug? Or What am I doing wrong?